# React Router is not working and returns a blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-component, multi-page-application

I am trying to develop a multi-page React App and I tried to use React Router but when I hit Save and reload the page I get a blank page.
This is what I have:
The Home component:

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import AboutUs from './components/AboutUs';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

export default function Home() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
        <AboutUs />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
}
```

This is App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import { Route, Router, browserHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Router exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Router>
  );
}
```

And finally this is the `index.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

When I hit Save and reload the page, because I am doing this on [replit.com](https://replit.com), all I get is a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

I tried to import `Router` from `react-router-dom` and wrap my `<Route />` tags within a `<Router />` tag and still get the same.

Comment: Inside router you were using Router instead route: try this:<Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Router>

Comment: Can you tell your `react-router-dom` version and are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: @yousoumar I have 3 errors:
Two of this:
You cannot render a  inside another . You should never have more than one in your app.
An another one:
The above error occured in the <Router> component

Comment: @Chellappanவ it doesn't work...!

Comment: Just in you've missed it or haven't taken the [tour] yet, there are 100% completely optional actions you can do after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps curate content on the site. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of your App component

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./home";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes >
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>} />
    </Routes>
);
}
```

Use `Routes` instead of `Router` and use `element` prop in `Route` to specify what will be rendered.

As for history, you can use `useNavigate` hook:

```
  const nav = useNavigate();
  const handleCheckout = () => nav("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. You are rendering an additional `Router` instead of `Route` for the `Home` component
2. You are already rendering a `BrowserRouter` in the index file, there's no need for any additional router components as you need only one for the entire app.

## Solution

Fix the home page route.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Remove all extraneous routers. I suggest rendering the `Route` components into a `Switch`.

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      ... other more specific routes by path ...
      <Router path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Based on the errors you mention in one of the comments I think you might actually be using `react-router-dom@6`. The `Switch` component was replaced by a `Routes` component and the `Route` component API changed significantly.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Router path="/" element={<Home />} />
      ... other routes ...
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-is-not-working-and-returns-a-blank-page]

Comment: Yeah my version is 6.3.0
I did the what you said but I still get a blank page
Should I try to use react-router-dom@5 an use Switch?

Comment: I just checked and I have this warning in my console
"Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page"

Comment: @Alin-AlexandruPeter That means you are rendering a `Route` component on `path="/"` but there isn't any `element` prop passed. What exactly are you rendering then?

Comment: It owrks if I add the element prop and  wrap my component between tags, like element={<Home />}

Answer (score 0):

If you have used Router in HomePage and want to use it again in other pages, just use Routes and not Router, as follows

```js
<div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/home'  exact element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path='/reports' element={<Reports/>} />
          <Route path='/products' element={<Products/>} />
        </Routes>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!